# Conditional probability proof for exponential distribution

Tags: probability-theory

For some exponential pdf with mean $1$.

I need to prove that $\mathbb{P}(x>t+s\mid x>s) = \mathbb{P}(x>t)$ for all $t,s \geq 0$.

All I've got so far is using the conditional rule. A couple steps would be helpful so I can get the ball rolling.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some hints:

1. Since $s,t\geq 0$,
   $$ \mathbb{P}(X>t+s\mid X>s)=\frac{\mathbb{P}(X>t+s,X>s)}{\mathbb{P}(X>s)}=\frac{\mathbb{P}(X>t+s)}{\mathbb{P}(X>s)} $$
2. Since $X$ is exponentially distributed with mean $1$, it follows that
   $$ \mathbb{P}(X>a)=e^{-a} $$
   for all $a\geq 0$.

Comment: I managed to find the answer as follows; 

$\mathbf e^-(t+s) / e^-s = e^-t = P(x>t)$

the only step I am a bit confused on is how $\mathbf P(x>t+s,X>s) = P(x>t+s)$

Comment: The event $\{X>t+s\}$ is contained in the event $\{X>s\}$, so their intersection is the smaller event, namely $\{X>t+s\}$.